# Environment Variable in React-js

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, environment-variables

Have an environment variable in my project as

```
process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API
```

which a google api key and use it to render map and have the below code which is not working:

```
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: (process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API)
})(MapContainer)
```

But when I use the api key directly it is rendering the map

```
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
      apiKey: ('AI************************')
 })(MapContainer)
```

How do I use the google api key as environment variable in the above code?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Webpack to bundle the code, there is [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)
Sample code -

```
// webpack.config.js
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  GOOGLE_MAPS_API: JSON.stringify(process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API)
})
```

app.js

```
console.log(GOOGLE_MAPS_API); // logs API_KEY
```